# Top (New) Users in Yearly Leagues

Tags: discussion, statistics, new-users

Every year, the users of Literature Stack Exchange can be ranked by their reputation earned in that year, and the yearly leagues are recorded at `stackexchange.com/leagues`, including each user's rise and fall compared with the previous year. It's interesting to see, not only who takes the top spot (usually one of the top few users by overall reputation), but also which *newer* user takes the top spot among people who were *not previously ranked* in the yearly leagues.

| Year | Year's top user | Top new user | ←'s yearly rank/rep | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [**2017**](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/668/year/literature/2017-01-01) | [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17/rand-althor) | [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17/rand-althor) | **#1** / **~22k** | First year of the site's existence. |
| [**2018**](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/668/year/literature/2018-01-02) | [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17/rand-althor) | [Gareth Rees](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/3003/gareth-rees) | **#3** / **~5k** |  |
| [**2019**](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/668/year/literature/2019-01-02) | [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17/rand-althor) | [Laurel](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/5747/laurel) | **#10** / **~750** | An inactive year, with nobody over 6k. |
| [**2020**](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/668/year/literature/2020-01-02) | [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/tsundoku) | [Mary](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/10061/mary) | **#7** / **~3k** |  |
| [**2021**](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/668/year/literature/2021-01-02) | [Gareth Rees](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/3003/gareth-rees) | [Namaskaram](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/12702/namaskaram) | **#16** / **~850** |  |
| [**2022**](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/668/year/literature/2022-01-02) | [Gareth Rees](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/3003/gareth-rees) | [Clara Diaz Sanchez](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/11734/clara-diaz-sanchez) | **#10** / **~2k** | Top 3 unchanged from previous year. |
| [**2023**](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/668/year/literature/2023-01-02) | [Gareth Rees](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/3003/gareth-rees) | [CDR](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/18523/cdr) | **#12** / **~2k** | Second year with nobody over 10k. |
| [**2024**](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/668/year/literature/2024-01-02) |  |  |  | Come back after a year for updates! |

---

<sub>*[super-fast voice at the end of advert]* All statistics are according to the linked Leagues pages, and may be inexact thanks to the [Great Rep Reshuffle of 2019](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/), which retroactively affected many records. Rep figures are given approximately, both because of this and because the leagues seem slightly buggy (how can the year rep be more than the total rep?) Users who have since deleted their profiles are not included. Terms and conditions apply.</sub>

Comment: Re: 'come back after a year'... At this rate it's gonna be @verbose for top user in 2024, by many miles. That aside, this is a great site with great questions and great answers and extraordinarily knowledgeable users. I've enjoyed participating here.

Comment: @CDR Thanks! I've enjoyed your participation here too, many thoughtful questions and well-referenced answers - congrats on topping the 2023 league! Re 2024, I'm also rooting for verbose (it would fit the pattern, one user 3 years running and then another), but it's impossible to predict in January, and probably "this rate" won't be kept up. What's for sure is that Tsundoku, Gareth Rees, and verbose are all among those "extraordinarily knowledgeable users" who deserve their places at the top of the all-time reputation league.

Comment: Thanks @CDR, but I neither spend as much time *consistently* as Gareth or Rand al'Thor on the site, nor do my answers get as many upvotes as theirs or Tsundoku's. Now that Tsundoku is answering again, I'd bet both of them will be duking it out for top spot in 2024.I agree with OP that your contributions to the site are great.

Comment: Is this the first year this was posted? I do not remember hearing that I was the top new user of 2019 (nor do I have any idea how that happened), but I guess I'll accept this accolade now, four years later lol

Comment: @Laurel Yes. It's been posted on SFF and Puzzling for a few years, but this is the first time I've brought the tradition to Lit. Now we can keep updating this post each January. Belated congrats :-)